# Call another function from another controller in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to call a function that is in another controller having get a response

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('mini_cart', function($scope, $http) {   
  $scope.update = function() {
    alert("Updated");
  }
  $scope.update();
});
```

I want to call this update method on this controller

```
app.controller('item_detail', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.update(); //But this is not working
});
```

Is there any way if that method can be called?

Comment: Use broadcast in angular, and capture the broadcast in the other controller

Comment: @Kaushik Is the item_detail controller a child of the controller mini_cart if so how many controllers are between them?

Answer (score 2):

In my answer I use variables for example, but you can do the same things with function call.

### 1st way: use services

Services are singletons and you can pass data through services. For example, let's call our service `dataservice`:

```
angular
  .module('app')
  .controller('FirstController', ['dataservice']);

function FirstController(dataservice) {
  dataservice.dataToPass = 'data to pass through controllers';
}
```

And you can get this data from second controller like this:

```
angular
  .module('app')
  .controller('SecondController', ['dataservice']);

function SecondController(dataservice) {
  let dataFromFirstController = dataservice.dataToPass;
}
```

### 2nd way: use $emit/$broadcast (only if controllers are the parent and the child)

You can pass data **up** via `$emit` or **down** via `$broadcast` ($emit and $broadcast works similar, I'll show the example only with $broadcast). If `FirstController` is the parent and `SecondController` is the child, you can pass data through them like this:

```
angular
  .module('app')
  .controller('FirstController', ['$scope']);

function FirstController($scope) {
  $scope.$broadcast('passDataFromParentToChild', 'Data from FirstController');
}
```

And get data in `SecondController`:

```
angular
  .module('app')
  .controller('SecondController', ['$scope']);

function SecondController($scope) {
  $scope.$on('passDataFromParentToChild', function (event, data) {
    console.log(data); // will be "Data from FirstController"
  });
}
```

### 3rd way: use $scope.$parent (only if controllers are the parent and the child)

If you want to change variable of parent controller from the child controller, here is the easiest way (let's assume that `FirstController` is the parent of `SecondController`):

```
angular
  .module('app')
  .controller('FirstController', ['$scope']);

function FirstController($scope) {
  $scope.varFromParentController = 'First';
}
```

Let's change `$scope.varFromParentController` from `SecondController`:

```
angular
  .module('app')
  .controller('SecondController', ['$scope']);

function SecondController($scope) {
  $scope.$parent.varFromParentController = 'Second';
}
```

### About $rootScope

You can also use `$rootScope`, but it's a bad practice, better choose one of the above ways.

Answer (score 1):

you can either use $rootScope which is shared through your app...

or better yet, use a service to "host" your function.
you can read more about services [Here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services)

Answer (score 1):

Implement the logic of your app in [services](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services).

To update the scope and keep scope variables in sync with your service fields you could do.

**1. Observer service (recommended)**

Create a service for observer handling.

```
app.service("observerService", function () {

    var observerCbFns = [];

    //Registers an oberserver function.
    function registerObserverFn(observerCbFn) {
        observerFns.push(observerCbFn);
    }

    //Call this to inform your observers.
    function notifyObservers() {
        observerCbFns.forEach(function (fn) {
            fn && fn();
        });
    }

    return {
        observer: {register: registerObserverFn, notify: notifyObservers}
    };
});
```

Now you can extend all of your services with observerService.

```
app.service("myService", function (observerService) {

    var parent = angular.extend({},observerService);

    var myValue;

    function setValue(value){
        myValue = value;
        parent.observer.notify(); //Notify each observer that myValue changed
    }

    function getValue(){
        return myValue;
    }

    return angular.extend(parent,{
        setValue: setValue,
        getValue: getValue
    });
});
```

Controllers should be [thin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thin_client). Which means there should be no of the actual logic of your app. Use controllers only for updating the scope. Doing so you will get clean well structured readable and easily reusable code.

```
app.controller('mini_cart',function($scope,$http,myService){

    function init(){
        myService.observer.register(updateScope);
    }
    init();

    function updateScope(){
        $scope.myValue = myService.myValue;
        alert("Updated");
    }

});
```

**2. $scope.$watch**

You could also use the following code to update your scope variables based on the service fields.

```
$scope.$watch(myService.getValue,function(){
    $scope.myValue = myService.getValue();
});
```

But that can have an impact on performance because the digest cycle gets called more often. I recommend **1.** if possible.